# How to pass an array from view to controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, view, controller, parameter-passing

In my view I need to add (dynamically) text inputs and I need to get theirs values in the controller (once the user submit the corresponding form).

My inputs are:

```
<input type="text" name="airports_input_origin" class="airports_input_origin" id="airports_input_origin_0" size="40"/> 

<input type="text" name="airports_input_origin" class="airports_input_origin" id="airports_input_origin_1" size="40"/>
```

etc... etc...

They all have the same 'name' attribute.... so I guessed that if I do

```
params[:airports_input_origin]
```

I'd get the array ... but I was wrong...

How can I get those values?

Thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to do something like so:

```
<input type="text" name="airports_input_origin[0]" class="airports_input_origin" id="airports_input_origin_0" size="40"/> 

<input type="text" name="airports_input_origin[1]" class="airports_input_origin" id="airports_input_origin_1" size="40"/>
```

Rails understand that it's an array if you tag numbers like that within the name.

So you could have a JavaScript function that iterates over all the inputs and resets their numbers everytime a destination is added/deleted. Use regex to replace the numbers or you could probably even hard code the name and change the "[x]" if this is all that's required.

Comment: and the I should be able to params[:airports_input_origin].size or params[:airports_input_origin][0] ?