# ROR application - pass data from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to pass data from a view to controller using Javascript.  How do I do this ?  Specifically the information I wish to access in the controller is what option/s have been selected in a variable number (one to many) of selections on the screen.

I have a ROR application I am developing and on the "Companies - Drill Interests" screen I wish to use java/coffeescript to send data and invoke controller action.  In the controller I can't get access to all the data I need to respond.  That is I can' determine what "Saved Assumption" the user has selected.

From the Companies controller building array (should I be doing this or using another method) of saved assumptions.

```
def companies_drill_interests
    # intial display use first (if present) user drill evaluations
    @result_list = Array.new
    @company_listings.each do |cl|
      @drill_interests.each do |di|
        target_share_price = 0
        result = Hash.new
        result["cl_display_name"] = cl.display_name
        result["di"] = di.drill.name
        result["target_share_price"] = 0
        # if saved assumptions grab first assumption and then first target_share_price
        @matched_evaluation_assumption = 
          EvaluationAssumption.matched_eval_assum(@current_user.id,  di.drill_id)
          ...
          # code that builds result ...
          end
        end  
        @result_list << result
      end
    end
  end
```

from the screen partial views/companies/_companies_drill_interests

```
<%= simple_form_for @company,
    html: { class: 'infogroup',
    id: "x_company_drill_interests"} do |f| %>
  <div class="infogroup-header">Drill Interests</div>  
  <div class="infogroup-body">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="info"> 
     <th class="very_large_column lalign">Drill Name</th>   
     ...
     <% if @drill_interests.present? %>
       <% index = 0 %>
        <% @drill_interests.each do |drill_interest| %>  
          <%= fields_for "drill_interest[]", drill_interest do |di| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= drill_interest.drill.name %></td>
              <td class="ralign"><%= drill_interest.equity_percentage %></td>
              <% array_name = "evaluation_assumption" + index.to_s %>
              <td id="x_user_eval_assum" class='lalign large_column' data-targets="<%= @probability_json %>"> 
              <td> <%= select("mea_user_save_name", "id",
                  @assumptions[array_name].collect {|r| [ r["mea_user_save_name"], r["id"] ] },
                  { :include_blank => false })  %> </td>  
              <% index += 1 %>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
          ...
```

If the user changes the "Saved Asumptions" selection this is detected in jave/coffeescript.  From app/assets/javascript/companies.js.coffee

```
...
   $('#x_company_drill_interests').change((event) ->
          company_id = $('.form.companies_drill_interests').attr('data-companyid')
          event.preventDefault() 
          calculateResult company_id 
   )

calculateResult = (company_id)-> 
data = $('#x_company_drill_interests').serialize()
$.ajax
   url:"/companies/#{company_id}/projection.json",
   type:"post"
   ...
```

Display statement in Companies Controller for when the action I can't get to work is performed.

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
   ...
  def projection
    puts "================================="
    puts "params = " + params.to_s
    puts "=================================" 
    ...
```

In the logs output from this statement

```
params = {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"rFx8TBWnECUCxFiEBQ+0lTmkvhUKEJrUx/SlEQNPEP8=", "mea_user_save_name"=>{"id"=>""}, "action"=>"projection", "controller"=>"companies", "id"=>"18", "format"=>"json"}.  The arrays are not present.
```

Overview of relationships between models.
Company has 0 to many drill_Interests.  Each Drill_interest has 0 to many Evaluation_Assumptions (and using Evaluation_Assumptions I wish to display User_Evaluation_Results).

If you wish to see above you can visit the application as per instructions below. 
1- go to http://quiet-fortress-3338.herokuapp.com/users/login
2- login with userid = pmlc and password = gmfive99
3- select companies from menu top RHS
4- select ADO
5- Select screen "Companies Drill Interests"
You will see ADO has an interest in both "Temp-01" and "ZZZ-Unlimited" with a number of saved assumptions for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send and array to backend using fields the fields must be named

```
<input name="myfieldarray[]">
```

In this way form.serialize() sends an array for myfieldarray.

check this question

[How to pass an array from view to controller in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626636/how-to-pass-an-array-from-view-to-controller-in-ruby-on-rails)

try this.

```
select_tag "my_array_param[]", options_from_collection_for_select(@assumptions[array_name].collect {|r| [ r["mea_user_save_name"], r["id"] ] }, "id", "mea_user_save_name"), include_blank: true
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `fields_for`, so change:

```
<td> <%= select("mea_user_save_name", "id",
                 @assumptions[array_name].collect {|r| [ r["mea_user_save_name"], r["id"] ] },
                { :include_blank => false })  %> </td>
```

to

```
<td> <%= di.select("mea_user_save_name", "id",
                  @assumptions[array_name].collect {|r| [ r["mea_user_save_name"], r["id"] ] },
                  { :include_blank => false })  %> </td>
```

Comment: changing " <td> <%= select("mea_user_save_name " to " <td> <%= di.select("mea_user_save_name " gives error "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Company with 'id'=undefined:
"

Answer (score 1):

Try to use select_tag instead of select

Comment: Have been trying select_tag but haven't got it working.  How does the statement look ?

Answer (score 1):

select_tag statement

```
select_tag "whatever_name", options_from_collection_for_select(@assumptions[array_name].collect {|r| [ r["mea_user_save_name"], r["id"] ] }, "id", "mea_user_save_name"), include_blank: true
```

Comment: Sontya - many thanks - how do I then pass results to controler?  Using "x_company_drill_interests" it looks in controller asthough no data has been sent from javascript to controller .

Comment: see this post it may help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459743/how-to-use-ajax-send-data-to-controller-in-ruby-on-rails]